# unable to set permissions to nfs shared sub folder

Tags: permissions, nfs

I have a common nfs folder under which i have many folders which needs to be accessed by particular users. how can i set subfolder permissions?? 
we create these folders from Linux and users access it from windows

new to Linux please bear with me :D

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
chmod -R ug+rw foldername
```

the -R means recursive. You have to enter this command as super user.

the ug+rw can be set to 644 or 755 (those are the permission types).

See the [chmod man page for more info](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)

Comment: the problem i'm facing is the users(clients) whom I've to provide reports are not added as users from my server side! is there any way i can set permissions?

Comment: i  want to restrict their access to subfolders

Comment: http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=45939&sid=352bff1901a5fc1693fc3b5b93423479 kinda problem

Comment: so omit the -R

755 means 

"(rwxr-xr-x) The file's owner may read, write, and execute the file. All others may read and execute the file. This setting is common for programs that are used by all users."

http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: Don't use -R and the other users will not be allowed to access any subfolders